# declare multiple objects in one line in java

Tags: java, object

I'm coding in **java** and I have a class *`Point`* with 3 differents constructors. I would like to create 3 objects with each constructor is one line. This is what I wrote :

```
Point p1 = new Point();
Point p2 = new Point(0.5, 6.);
Point p3 = new Point(p2);
```

Is it possible to write this on a single line ?
Thanks !

Comment: `Point p1 = new Point(); Point p2 = new Point(0.5, 6.); Point p3 = new Point(p2);` There you go.

Comment: If you store them in a single container (array or List), you can create them with a single statement. `Point[] points = {new Point(),new Point(x,y),new Point(z)};`

Comment: Why do you need all calls to the constructors in one line?

Comment: You can do it, as stated in the answers posted. But in most cases it's suggested to NOT do that, because it difficults code readability.

Comment: Thank you @GhostCat, I'm a new user on StackOverflow and it seems like I hadn't privilege to upvote. Thanks for remind !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean :

```
Point p1 = new Point(), p2 = new Point(0.5, 6.), p3 = new Point(p2);
```

I assume you have three different constructor in Point class.

---

But note, be careful, it will not work if you do :

```
Point p1 = new Point(), p3 = new Point(p2), p2 = new Point(0.5, 6.);// Error
                                       ^^   ^^
```

In this case the order is important, you have to evaluate the first Object `p1` then you can create the 3rd Object `p3` based on the 2nd one.

Comment: Thanks. This should be the prettiest way !

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer: not really.

Of course, you can just avoid the line break, and put

```
Point p1 = ... ; Point p2 = ...
```

on one line. Or:

```
Point p1 = new Point(), p2 = new Point(0.5, 6.), p3 = new Point(p2);
```

turning ;+linebreak into commas.

And just for the record: alone the fact that you are naming things "point1, point2, point3" is indicating that you are probably doing something wrong. Putting an index into the variable name basically means that you should rather use an array, list, or map.

The other important thing: your intention is always always always to write code that is *easy to read and understand* for other humans. Stuffing *more* information into a single line is (very often) not helping with this goal.

Answer (score 1):

Sure.

```
Point p1 = new Point(), p2 = new Point(0.5, 6), p3 = new Point(p2);
```

Comment: GMTA! ... well, to a certain degree ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can write each statements in a single line seperated by semi colon .

```
Point p1 = new Point(); Point p2 = new Point(0.5, 6.); Point p3 = new Point(p2);
```

or

```
Point p1 = new Point(), p2 = new Point(0.5, 6.), p3 = new Point(p2);
```

So line breaks can be avoided in java.

If you use **scala** , then concept of **`case classes`** can be used to achieve your expectation . In scala we don't need to use **`new`** keyword to instantiate an object . You can create the instannce directly as

**`val p1 = Point()`** 
or
**`val p2 = Point(0.5,6.)`** 
or 
**`val p3 = Point(p2)`** .

But you should have a suitable **case class** **Point** for this .